# Querying sub documents in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider following model in mongoose:

```
var specie = mongoose.Schema({
order: String,
family: String,
genus: String,
species: String,
properties: [
                {property:String,
                value:String}
            ]
});
```

I am trying to build a query that will return the documents based upon specific values in the properties array.

Below is an example of my query:

```
var query = {
    $and: [
        {"properties.property":"number of wings","properties.value":"2"},
        {"properties.property":"antenna end","properties.value":"clubbed"}
    ]
}
```

I thought this query would work but it actually returns all document that have a property "number of wings" and "antenna end" and a value "4" and value "clubbed".

I want the query to return those documents that have following objects in the properties array:

```
{property: "number of wings", value: "2"} and 
{property: "antenna end", value:"clubbed"}
```

However the above query also returns the documents who have following property:

```
{property: "number of legs", value:"2"}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found my own answer. 
I have to use $elemMatch in the query:

```
var query = {
    $and: [
        {properties: {$elemMatch: {property:"number of wings",value:"2"}}},
        {properties: {$elemMatch: {"property":"antenna end","value":"clubbed"}}}
    ]
}
```

Adding the resource link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents

This seems to return the correct results.